# Do I need to repeat common portions of a selector or is there a nicer way?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to have something like the following (like a `||` ):

```
[.pw-each-placecomment or .pw-each-usercomment] h2 { }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What's wrong with:
.pw-each-placecomment h2, pw-each-usercomment h2 {/*css*/}

Comment: @maaachine It's not very DRY which is what I assumed the OP was getting at.

Comment: thx @maaachine , we do have a lot of these so its greater than just these two (it's could be a huge css refactoring). I was hoping something a bit more logical. We are using SASS (sass-bootstrap) so that probably would provide something. thx for comment - will probably do what you suggested in iterim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with plain CSS right now. Firefox has introduced the non-standard [`:any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aany), but it's experimental and only in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. It may make it in as `:matches()`, so keep an eye on it.

If you don't use a CSS preprocessor, such as SASS, Stylus, LESS, etc, you're tough out of luck.

You'll have to list 'em both out.

```
.pw-each-placecomment h2,
.pw-each-usercomment h2 {

}
```

Comment: thx, will probably do something like this and then SASS later.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the attribute selector.

The ^ (carat) symbol indicates the beginning of a string (here- the beginning of the class name):

```
div[class^="pw-each-"] h2 {  
   color: red;  
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/r34Sv/)**

**This would select any h2 element with an ancestor div with a class name that starts with "pw-each-"**

So **for example:** pw-each-placecomment and pw-each-usercomment - would match... but

pw-other-other or  other-pw-each-placecomment- wouldn't.

For more info about this selector (and selectors in general) - I recommend [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Comment: This selects the `h2` within a `div` that satisfies that condition (as intended by the asker). It doesn't select the `div`.